# TypedDict does not show any error for mandatory fields

Tags: python, dictionary, typeddict

I am using TypedDict, for creating some rules for my dictionary. When I am passing my one key value pair and not passing the other keys and values it is still printing the output and not showing any error to pass the mandatory fields.

```
from typing import TypedDict

class Persons(TypedDict):
    name : str
    year : str

person: Persons = {'name': 'Person1'}

print(person)
```

And getting output as

```
{'name': 'Person1'}
```

Can anyone please help me, what mistake I am making here?

Comment: Python doesn't do type checking at runtime. You have to use a tool like `mypy`.

Comment: And if you are using a Python-aware editor, it should also give you a warning about this line.  But as @barmar mentions, Python does no type checking at run time.

Comment: @FrankYellin, I am using VS code with the python extensions.

Comment: See https://www.emmanuelgautier.com/blog/enable-vscode-python-type-checking for how to enable type checking in vscode.